# How to check current browser against the list of supported ones

Tags: browser, webpack, browser-detection

We have a list of browsers we test our webapp in. I have a task to notify the user if his browser isn't supported or tested to work well with our app.

We have a `browserslist` configuration in the project and I'm looking for a way to test current browser against the list.
I tried `browserlist-useragent` but we can't compile it with webpack due to the fact it uses `net`, `fs`, `tls` and other native node modules we don't want to include in our bundle.

Is there any better way do avoid copying the list of supported browsers in many different places and just use browserlist configuration that already exists to detect if user uses supported one or not?

Comment: As far as I can tell, the problem is that browserslist tends to be aggressively generated, like "we commit to support the last 2 version of each browser". However, it doesn't mean the app won't work for version N-3, it's more an annoucement to the world than a real technical constraint. Thus checking on browserslist automatically is maybe not that useful. Instead you'd lock out manually browser that obviously won't work (like IE).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd consider using this "utility" package `https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist-useragent-regexp` in the project that uses `browserslist`, and then use the file generated by the script suggested by this package to then use anywhere else.
In reality, all you want is the regex in the generated file. This can be placed in any client or server code you need for browser detection. I've placed mine in some classic asp.

Also note that on a Windows PC, the instructions provided don't result in a file containing a RegEx. Instead, you'd need to run `npx browserslist-useragent-regexp --allowHigherVersions` to display a suitable RegEx on your console, and then add that where needed.

Comment: The issue of script not working on Windows has been fixed by Dan Onoshko here: https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist-useragent-regexp/issues/36