# Browserlist match JS function

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack

How can I test if current browser matches the `browserslist` specified in my `npm`/`webpack` project? For some reason, I need to know if the browser doesn't match the `browserslist` and do a redirection or similar. I'd like to have a function like

```
if (browserslist_match()) ...
```

How would you do that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48808774/how-to-check-current-browser-against-the-list-of-supported-ones